# Cicle FOR to generate two sequences of numbers

Tags: c

I use this code to create a number sequence, but what i want is increment a second sequence of numbers(each 1000 times 'i' increment, 'j' the second increment of 1)

```
 for (i=0;i<5000;i++)
                {
                printf("/sample/%d/%d\n",j,i+1);
                }
```

what i want is this:

/sample/0005/0005000

Comment: Start by reading a [`printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and learn about the formatting codes, and how you could set field widths and padding. Then experiment with it until you get your desired result.

Comment: dont understand, is there a relationship between 0005 and 0005000

Comment: yes the relationship is that each 1000 times one variable increment, the second increment by 1.EXAMPLES: /sample/0001/1000 or /sample/0006/6000 or /sample/0008/8000

Comment: it would help if you posted a few more lines with this relationship

Comment: Do you mean `0000/0000001...0000/999999999, 0001/0000000...`?

Comment: Oh, I think I start to see what you mean. So in addition to the advice in my previous comment I also advice you to think how you could get e.g. `5` from `5000`, or `3` from e.g. `3000` to `3999`. Hint: It has to do with division.

Comment: something like: var  j = i\1000;

Comment: @localsixosix Yes! In C you would write `(i+1)/1000`. `/` for `int` expressions means integer division in C.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
#include <usual.h>

int main(  )
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int ticker = 1000;

  for ( i = 0; i < 5001; i++ )
  {
    if ( i && i % ticker == 0 )
    {
      j++;
      ticker += 1000;
      printf( "\n sample i== %d   j== %d ", i, j );
    }       
  }         
}
```

Comment: useful, but i need the zeros in the begin of number: example: for (i=0000002; i<0000100;i++) { printf("%d",i+1);} and this is not what i want because i want print 0000002....to 0000100.

Comment: thank you. i moved to new TOPIC : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239373/print-number-from-0000002-to-0000100-with-zeros